# models.DateTimeField() Time is always 1 hour less

Tags: python, django

below is part of the code of my django models.Model class. If I set in admin panel for example 17.03.2018 14:00 it saves correctly this model with correct date and time. But if I print result it returns one hour less 17.03.2018 13:00. How can i fix it?

```
...
starts_at = models.DateTimeField()
...

beginnt_date = json.dumps(starts_at.date().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
beginnt_zeit = json.dumps(starts_at.time().strftime("%H:%M"), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
result = []
result.append({
    'beginnt_date': beginnt_date,
    'beginnt_zeit': beginnt_zeit,
})

print(result)    
>>> [{'beginnt_date':"17-03-2018", 'beginnt_zeit':"12:38"}]
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at pytz on how to convert time between timezones, as django uses it to implement the datetimefield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django [interprets datetimes in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-input-in-forms) as being in the *current time zone*, which in your case is `Europe/Zurich`. All datetimes are then [saved to the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) as `UTC`, which is one hour behind that. So what you're seeing in your `print` statement is the time in `UTC`.

The normal way you'd change the displayed timezone is by using [`timezone.activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone), which affects the redering of templates (among other things). If you're creating an API you'll usually want to stick with `UTC`.

All that said, if you do want to convert the datetime object you can do so with pytz, a required dependency of Django:

```
from pytz import timezone

starts_at_local = starts_at.astimezone(timezone("Europe/Zurich"))
print(starts_at_local.time().strftime("%H:%M"))  # should be what you're expecting
```

Comment: I read this documentation, but I did not understand how to return the correct date. could you pls give an example.

Comment: exactly. thank you very much. I just added following
`beginnt_zeit = json.dumps(match.starts_at.astimezone(timezone("Europe/Zurich")).time().strftime("%H:%M"), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)` and it retutsn right time

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having an issue with my time always being off by 1 hour, but it was because I had set `TIME_ZONE = 'MST'` in my `settings.py` file. I changed it to `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver'` and that fixed the issue. It seems the longer name accounts for daylight savings automatically.

In my efforts to solve my off-by-1 error, I discovered this. Although it didn't directly answer my question, the `Europe/Zurich` part of Kevin's answer gave a clue and I wanted to share my solution with future readers.